Pagina HTML com pptx
Estou trabalhando em uma pagina web em html, nela preciso colocar uma apresentação de Power point, para inserir essa apresentação usei recurso do próprio office, desta forma:


<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
           <head>
            <iframe src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?resid=FAEDB483F8327CCF%2173431&amp;authkey=!AKEVDK0isdR2Ip0&amp;em=2&amp;wdAr=1.7777777777777777" width="476px" height="288px" frameborder="0">Este é um apresentação do <a target="_blank" href="https://office.com">Microsoft Office</a> incorporado, da plataforma <a target="_blank" href="https://office.com/webapps">Office</a>.</iframe>
           </head>

</html>



Porem preciso que o slides passem de forma automática, sem necessidade de ficar clicando para mostrar os slides seguintes

Não duplique perguntas, as orientações dos ajustes estão no comentário na pergunta original. Se precisar comentar faça na outra pergunta.
